# Can a user with 10k reps view recently deleted posts of another user?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Can a user with 10k reps view recently deleted posts (including Questions and Answers) of another user?

Comment: You mean like this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261171/unable-to-access-triage-review-queue-on-stackoverflow Google sees everything. However, it takes 10k to access the old links and no one can view your exact list that is available inside of your profile.

Comment: @TravisJ link is broken

Comment: @Developer_ACE - It isn't broken. It just requires 10k reputation to view deleted posts (that link was to a post by Starkeen which he removed himself).

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

You can only see what you already have the link to.

Comment: In theory we could go over [Recently deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) but that shows recently deleted posts of *some* other users, not a specific user.....